# How to print variable's value without a space char

Tags: asp.net

I'm a newbie in `ASP.NET` and I've one question.Let I've an `ASP.NET` code snippet:

```
var nam="Mik";
var name="Spenser";
```

But if trying to print `Mike` the `Spenser` is printing instead:

```
<p>This name is @name</p>
```

Is it possible to print `@nam`+`e` without a space and renaming of the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using MVC you can state the variable as follows

```
@(nam)e
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this since ASP.NET MVC 3, you can use:

```
@Html.Raw(myString)
```